# Kotlin visibility modifier for own file and extension methods

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to have an `object` that encapsulates some logic such that it is visible only to itself and any extensions I define on it.
This is because my class is huge as it's essentially several ETL scripts working together for data replication.
I would typically use partial classes, but Kotlin doesn't have that feature.

So next best is `extensions` but it seems extensions can't access `private`, `protected` can't be used in `object`s and `internal` makes methods visible to the whole module.

What is the best solution?

Sample listing (pseudo code, doesn't compile for visibility issues)

```
public object MyObject {
   public fun entryMethod() { extension() }

   private fun privateMethod() { }
}

// in another file...
private fun MyObject.extension() { privateMethod() }
```

Changing all `private` visibility modifiers to be `internal` lets the code work but now other code in my app can access `privateMethod` or `extension()` :(

```
public object MyObject {
   public fun entryMethod() { extension() }

   internal fun privateMethod() { }
}

// in another file...
internal fun MyObject.extension() { privateMethod() }
```

Comment: You've listed all the possibilities and their downsides. You will have to choose one.  There aren't any secret options you're missing.

Comment: If you hypothetically could do this, you've exposed these functions to be visible in other files, so it's already exposed to other classes in the module anyway, because they could just get around the limitation by defining a function as an extension function.

Comment: well that's fine but then it's different from reflection stand point. So at compile-time, sure, but there is a difference at runtime.
Ultimately, of course, I'd love for there to just be a way to define partial classes :(